# Embedding HTTP iframe in HTTPS iframe for HTTPS site?

Tags: https, http, iframe, embed

My site is HTTPS. I'm using Wix to edit my site, and Wix no longer accepts HTTP embeds. I wish to embed a flight tracker plugin which is HTTP but I do not expect the developer of this site to be switching to HTTPS anytime soon.

Is it possible to embed the HTTP plugin in a HTTPS iframe on a friend's SSL-secured site and then embed this HTTPS page in Wix?

```
<iframe src="http://www.vafinancials.com/v5/plugins/last_ten_flights.php?id=18517&w=0" 

frameborder="0" width="100%" height="325px" scrolling="auto"><p>Your browser does not 

support iframes</p></iframe>
```

Comment: @Tom: Sounds like a good idea, how would I go about doing this though? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**You can't include an http iframe in an https website.**

What you can do is hosting yourselves an https version of that iframe, like a proxy for example.

Comment: how to create the proxy instead ?